# Why maven do not "add" all dependencies? (on spring example)

Tags: dependencies, maven

I add sprig dependency to my maven pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
</dependency>
```

I "run" maven to download all dependencies.
In spring pom file (from local .m2 repository) I can see many dependencies (about 20)

```
        .....
     </organization>
 <dependencies>
    <!-- External Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
   <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>asm</groupId>
   <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.3</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
        .....
```

But when I collect all libs by Assebly plugin or list all of them using "dependencies" task, I see that maven "use" only spring and commons-lang. No any others.

I just want to know whats happens or what I am doing wrong? Why maven do not "add" all dependencies from spring pom?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml

Comment: commons-logging instead commons-lang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These dependencies are marked as optional (`<optional>true</optional>`) in the pom.  Hence they do not get included.